# Unir dos consultas similares de una misma tabla en PostgreSQL

Tags: base-de-datos, postgresql

he generado dos consultas a una base de datos PostgreSQL, las cuales son las siguientes:

```
SELECT empresa, count(registro) AS "Aprobados" from mi_tabla WHERE
registro = 'APROBADO' GROUP BY  empresa;
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
SELECT empresa, count(registro) AS "Reprobados" from mi_tabla WHERE
registro = 'REPROBADO' GROUP BY  empresa;
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi pregunta es, ¿cómo puedo unir las dos consultas anteriores en una sola consulta con el fin de producir un resultado similar al siguiente?:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He utilizado `UNION` pero no consigo los resultados esperados. Adjunto un código de ejemplo de la base de datos que estoy utilizando: [Demo-RexTest](https://rextester.com/RWBXA80294).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sin conocer la estructura de las tablas ni los datos que contienen me atrevería proponerte utilizar las dos consultas que ya tienes como sub consultas, luego las unes mediante un `join` puesto que tienen el campo `empresa` en común:

```
SELECT a.empresa, a.Aprobados, b.Reprobados
FROM (
   SELECT empresa, count(registro) AS "Aprobados" from mi_tabla WHERE
   registro = 'APROBADO' GROUP BY  empresa
) a
INNER JOIN (
   SELECT empresa, count(registro) AS "Reprobados" from mi_tabla WHERE
   registro = 'REPROBADO' GROUP BY  empresa
) b on a.empresa = b.empresa
```

Esta solución es válida si en las dos consultas hay las mismas empresas. En otro caso deberíamos pensar en otra solución.

Comment: En este caso, en ambas consultas siempre hay las mismas empresas, por lo que su solución si funcionó, muchas gracias.